# Can Tomcat 8 update new certificate(s) of the Java's keystore not need restart?

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

My web app run in Tomcat8 and need call a Web service that uses certificate authentication. I have import certificate to the Java's keystore, and web app can call web service (after restart Tomcat).
So, how to update new certificate to Tomcat is running not need restart ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a very downside of tomcat. He will not reload them automatically. Tomcat is a web-container, so webapps should be independent. It was possible by set a manager in tomcat7 for all webapps what was a design-misconstruction because the container's typical independence-character of webapps are broken.

In tomcat8 afaik they are read at the connector's initialization and changes are ignored after the connector's initialization. If you change the keystore, you have to shutdown the https-connector and reactivate it again in order to have a clean re-read of the keystore.

Comment: Using a mutual-authentication mechanism I noticed multiple problems in using keystore/chaining in tomcat8, what has worked in tomcat7.